Android/aosp Toast how to manage overlapping
i cannot find a way to manage my priority display of my toast over my windows.
In my aosp i have multiple display priority, let's say the level go from 0 (less) to 10 (top priority to display).
Multiple windows, popup, toast, dropdown menu, etc.. will be displayed, and in my current environment if i display a toast
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is my Toast message!",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

My toast  will be hidden by some menu, and i can't find a way to manage it.
The Toast offical doc does not seem to manage such things.
Chatgpt and similar AI speak about a priority setting in the WindowManager.LayoutParams but it doesn't appear to exist.
Any help is welcome.

Something weird is happening here because Toasts are always drawn on top of everything in your application. There’s not even an option to configure it.

Have to agree with @Tenfour04. Since Toast aren't part of the MaterialDesign guidelines anymore, I would recommend using either notifications or snackbars: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts#alternatives_to_using_toasts

Thank for the info, i will check that
